# Count Up start automatic

Tags: javascript

How to set count up to not run automatically?
i want to make that count up just start when i scrolling on it

**html code :**

```
<!-- COUNT UP -->
    <div id="countup" class="countup parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/basic/background-count.jpg"><!-- start countup div-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <h2>The <b>Count</b></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                <br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</p>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="counter" data-count="350">0</h3>
                    <h4>Project</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="counter" data-count="755">0</h3>
                    <h4>Coffee</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="counter" data-count="2500">0</h3>
                    <h4>Smile</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                    <h3 class="counter" data-count="50">0</h3>
                    <h4>Employee</h4>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END COUNT UP -->
```

**Javascript code :**`

```
 $('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },

  {

    duration: 5000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }
  });  
});
```

**And this the ss :**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.counter').hover(
function(){
var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },

  {

    duration: 5000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }
  });  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countup" class="countup parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/basic/background-count.jpg"><!-- start countup div-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <h2>The <b>Count</b></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                <br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</p>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="counter" data-count="350">0</h3>
                    <h4>Project</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="counter" data-count="755">0</h3>
                    <h4>Coffee</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="counter" data-count="2500">0</h3>
                    <h4>Smile</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                    <h3 class="counter" data-count="50">0</h3>
                    <h4>Employee</h4>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Try this

Comment: thanks for help me but that just start when i hover it right?do you have another solution?i want make it start when i scroll on it

Comment: @Zuhri sorry, i didnt get you

Comment: this is the example of my web http://upto.esy.es/ check the bottom of the page, the count start counting by itself(automatic) and i cant see the animate do you have a soulution how to fix it?